# Intercepting the OpenFcn of a block mask

Tags: simulink

Simulink 2010b question:

I am trying to initialise a mask's parameters when the mask opens, however despite the name, the inisialisation function in the mask only executes when the mask closes.

I thought to simply add some code to the `OpenFcn` callback that would run before the mask opens, but this appears to interfere with the mask's own opening that seems to also use the callback. My override stops the mask from opening. Is there a way of calling the mask's `OpenFcn` callback after mine, or, in some other way calling some inisialisation code before the mask opens?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly dirty answer, the parameters run their callback code *before* they are changed, on open of the dialog, in the order they are defined. I created an invisible parameter whose only purpose was to house the initialisation code for the remaining parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the OpenFcn callback and after your code add open_system(gcb, 'mask'); that it will open the block's mask as if it were not overriden